# Python regular expression to find letters and numbers

Tags: python, regex

Entering a string

I used `'findall'` to find words that are only letters and numbers (The number of words to be found is not specified).

I created:

`words = re.findall ("\ w * \ s", x) # x is the input string`
If i entered `"asdf1234 cdef11dfe a = 1 b = 2"`
these sentences seperated `asdf1234, cdef11dfe, a =, 1, b =, 2`
I would like to pick out only `asdf1234`, `cdef11dfe`

How do you write a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work : `(?<![\"=\w])(?:[^\W_]+)(?![\"=\w])`

**Explanation**

`(?:[^\W_])+` Anything but a non-word character or an underscore at least one time (non capturing group)

`(?<![\"=\w])` not precedeed by `"` or a word character

`(?![\"=\w])` not followed by `"` or a word character

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RI0sW7/2)

**Sample code** [Run online](https://repl.it/IXUq/1)

```
import re

regex = r"(?<![\"=\w])(?:[^\W_]+)(?![\"=\w])"

test_str = "a01a b02 c03 e dfdfd abcdef=2 b=3 e=4 c=\"a b\" aaa=2f f=\"asdf 12af\""

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    print (match.group())
```

Comment: thanks answer but i need more help if i entered  
"a01a b02 c03 e dfdfd abcdef=2 b=3 e=4 c="a b" aaa=2f f="asdf 12af""
i want only pick  a01a, b02, c03, e, dfdfd 
how do i create regular expression

Answer (score 1):

Try `/[a-zA-z0-9]{2,}/`.

This looks for any alphanumeric character (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`) at least 2 times in a row (`{2,}`).  That would be the only way to filter out the one letter words of the string.

The problem with `\w` is that it includes underscores.

Comment: thanks answer but i need more help if i entered  
"a01a b02 c03 e dfdfd abcdef=2 b=3 e=4 c="a b" aaa=2f f="asdf 12af""
i want only pick  a01a, b02, c03, e, dfdfd 
how do i create regular expression